# For what integral value of $n$ is $3\pi$ the period of the function $\cos(nx)\sin(5x/n)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For what integral value of $n$ is $3\pi$ the period of the function $\cos(nx)\sin(5x/n)$ ?

What should be the correct approach to this problem?Will taking the LCM of the periods of the two functions in product be equal to the period of the whole function?

I tried like period of $\cos(nx)$ is $2\pi$/n and $\sin(5x/n)$ is $2\pi n/5$ 
So the period should be L.C.M of $2\pi$/n and $2\pi n/5$.Which is equal to $2\pi n/\gcd(n,5)$. However after this I'm not being able to proceed. Help please!

Comment: So we want $\dfrac{2n}{\gcd(n,5)}=3$

Comment: @KennyLau Yes.But what next?

Comment: Note that $\gcd(n,5)$ must be either $1$ or $5$.

Comment: @KennyLau But why?

Comment: Because those are the only divisors of $5$, and $\gcd$ means greatest common divisor.

Comment: I think your assumption might be wrong.$3\pi$ is the fundamental period.What you took might be an integer multiple of fundamental.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Are you looking for the smallest period? For example $n=5$ has period $\pi$, but of course $3\pi$ is also a period.

Comment: No nothing like smallest period is mentioned in question @almagest

Comment: @SanchayanDutta It is unfortunate that you say in the first sentence and the title "the period". That normally means the smallest period. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @almagest Even i was not sure at first as my book doesnt state clearly.However my answer was not matching the one in book.The correct answer should be 15,5,3,1 and -15,-5,-3,-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for $n$ such that $3\pi$ is a period, but not necessarily the smallest period.

We have $2\cos nx\sin\frac{5x}{n}=\sin(\frac{5x}{n}+nx)+\sin(\frac{5x}{n}-nx)$. So we require $3(n\pm\frac{5}{n})$ to be an even integer. Clearly that is impossible for $|n|>15$ or for $n$ not a factor of 15. But equally clearly any factor of 15 (positive or negative) works.

So the answer is $n=\pm1,\pm3,\pm5,\pm15$.

Comment: "So we require $3(n±5n)$ to be an even integer".Why?

Comment: Put $f(x)=\sin(\frac{5x}{n}+nx)+\sin(\frac{5x}{n}-nx)$. We require that $f(x)=f(x+3\pi)$. Just plug that in. We know that the period of $\sin y$ is $2\pi$. [Note it is $\frac{5}{n}$ not $5n$.]

Comment: I put $x+3\pi$ in place of x.But i am not getting that term 3(n±5n).Could you please show a few steps if you don't mind.

Comment: $\sin(x(n+\frac{5}{n}))=\sin((x+3\pi)(n+\frac{5}{n}))$. So we want $3\pi(n+\frac{5}{n})=2\pi k$ or $3(n+\frac{5}{n})=2k$.

Comment: Oh I got it.Great work.Thanks a million tons :-)!

Comment: if you put the values of n in the original equation, then by LCM rule you dont get 3pi or 3k.pi as period. Please help